# Relatioship custom fields hide if no entries

Tags: templates, relationships

I am building site with EE v2.6.1 and I have following snippet in one of my template

```
<div class="content-main">
        <div class="titel">Features</div>    
        <div class="content-box">
          <ul class="features">
            {features}
            <li>
              <span>{features:title}</span>
              <img src="{features:icon}" width="65" height="55" alt=""> 
              {features:description}
            </li>
            {/features}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to hide the whole block if there is no entry in features relationship, is there any direct way or I need to use plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like:

```
{features}
    {if "{features:count}" == "1"}
    <div class="content-main">
            <div class="titel">Features</div>    
            <div class="content-box">
              <ul class="features">
    {/if}
                <li>
                  <span>{features:title}</span>
                  <img src="{features:icon}" width="65" height="55" alt=""> 
                  {features:description}
                </li>
    {if "{features:count}" == "{features:total_results}"}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
    {/if}
{/features}
```

I hope, it would work.

Comment: The repeating part is "li" under ul.feature, but I found the required condition